# Flask redirect on select onchange

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner to `flask` and I'm making a small web scraper app. What I've done so far has created a dropdown with a list of elements. Now I want to be able to render another page when the user selects a value from the list and I want to pass that value to the next page as well.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <select id = "foo" onchange="">
        {% for item in Citydata %}
            <option value = {{ item.link }}> {{ item.name }} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>   
{% endblock %}
```

This makes the list and adds in all the links and values. I know that what should happen is that when an option is selected a new route is selected/used and a new template file is loaded. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to submit a form. You can find a simple example of how to do that with Flask [here](http://opentechschool.github.io/python-flask/core/form-submission.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do a form submission, follow colidyre's suggestion.

It seems to me, however, that you're looking to add a variable in your path, so you will need to use Flask's [Variable Rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#variable-rules)

It is unclear what `item.link` is, however if you have formatted that to be associated with an item's id such as `/item/1`, you could create an `<a>` tag like so:

```
    {% for item in Citydata %}
        <a href = "{{ item.link }}"> {{ item.name }} </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

That would handle populating the href properly on the front-end, next you will need to set up the proper route on the server to handle the path:

```
    @app.route('/item/<int:item_id>')
    def item_route(item_id):
        # do some stuff
```

NOTE: you don't have to create `<a>` tags, but it is a bit more straight forward than `<option>`.  To stick with `<option>` you would just need to add some JavaScript client-side to call the back-end service based on the selected `<option>`'s `value` attribute instead.